# train-test split of scikit learn resulting in features having only one unique value in train data

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression, train-test-split

I am trying to train a multivariate linear regression model. I have a data set named 'main'. There are few categorical variable in this dataset. I dummified the categorical variable. Let's say the columns obtained after dummification are A, B, C, D and so on. Now when I am trying to run train-test split on this main dataset, the train dataset thus obtained has only values 0 in one of these columns. How can I overcome this problem.

The code which I am using is :

for train-test split:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(0)
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(main, train_size = 0.7, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)
```

On running the below code :

```
main.columns[main.nunique() == 1]
```

The result is : `Index([], dtype='object')`

And when running the below code for train data :

```
 df_train.columns[df_train.nunique() == 1]
```

The result is : `Index(['A', 'D', 'S'], dtype='object')`

I want the resulting train set to contain features with all combination of values in it. However, this split is giving me only one value in some features

Edit : I checked the unique values in these columns and these columns are highly unbalanced with only one value present for the positive case. I tries stratify and it needs at lease two rows of positive class. And this the case for many columns. So I cannot separately include this columnns in the train dataset as it would require writing code for all the columns. I want this to be done automatically.

Comment: Did you try `train_test_split` with `stratify` parameter?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show what's inside of the main dataframe

Comment: The stratify parameter sounds like it would help, but this is difficult to dissect with the data or at least the value_counts of the column in question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing random_state value ?